# Помогите разобратся с ресурсами в jar

Tags: java

Добрый день, есть желание выгружать в указанную папку .exe из ресурсов jar и в принципе я этого добился но как то "костыльно" проблема была в начале в том что метод

```
getResourceAsStream(Sp/Sp.txt)
```

не как не находил по указанному пути нужный файл который находился в папке которая была в корне пакета с классами. Далее это файл я положил к классам без папки и сменил расширение на .txt и о чудо заработало вот таким образом

```
InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("Sp.txt"); 
    System.out.println(in);
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
    FileOutputStream outF = new FileOutputStream("C://Users//Desktop/resources/Ton/Sp/Sp.exe//");
```

Но теперь к этому файлу нужно выгрузить ещё и файлы с расширением .dll а так же .ico но сними данный способ не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getResourceAsStream требует абсолютный путь (то есть начинающийся со `/`) таким образом правильный вариант будет `getResourceAsStream("/Sp/Sp.txt")`